# Find Stale/Inactive Exchange Mailboxes

Tags: email, exchange, powershell, email-server, exchange-2010

Hoping someone can help with this/it's an easy to explain issue, but basically I'm looking to find mailboxes in our Exchange 2010 environment that haven't been logged into for more than x days/a certain amount of time.

I've found several powershell scripts online which would/should seem to work by looking at the last logon time attribute for mailbox statistics, but when I try to export (or even just display the results in powershell), there seems to be a lot of mailboxes (but not all) that do not show any information for lastlogontime - it's just blank.

One of the scripts I used for example is below, but wondering if anyone has maybe a better way of finding this information or knows why these results aren't being generated as expected?  Thank You in advance for any help you can offer!

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | Where{$_.Lastlogontime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)} | Select DisplayName, LastLoggedOnUserAccount, LastLogonTime | Export-csv C:\Temp\InactiveUsers.csv
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last Logon time being blank usually means it hasn't been used at all. 
However I personally would adjust the script to remove the requirement for the time limit

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select DisplayName, LastLoggedOnUserAccount, LastLogonTime
```

Then export those results to CSV and sort the results by the dates involved. That will give you a better idea if the results you are getting back are expected.

This script on the TechNet gallery would give you better results though.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-Inactive-Mailboxes-on-1ac82ddf as it is based on the last sent item, rather than logon date. If you have a BES or other product that scans the mailboxes then the logon date can be very inaccurate.

Comment: LastLogonTime will be reset to blank if the mailbox is migrated between databases, FYI

Comment: @mfinni -- Thank You, I wasn't aware of that.  This is probably the case because when we off board employees we will move their mailbox to a different database.  I'm assuming if the mailbox is logged into again, it will edit the lastlogontime attribute?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

When you move a mailbox from one database to another, the LastLogonTime gets reset. In this case it would appear blank.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).